# What happens if you start a bounty on a question with an already-approved answer?

Tags: discussion, badges, bounty

Wondering about this because I am trying to get the [promoter](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/220/promoter) badge on SO. I only have a single question on SO (for which I have already approved an answer). Does the user that answered my question get the bounty, or does the reputation get lost in limbo? Is this considered bad behaviour, like seen as possible boosting of a user's rep?

Comment: You can manually award a bounty to an existing answer if you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties for more details.

Comment: Would I still get the badge if I award the bounty on the answer instead of my question? My goal here is specifically to get the promoter badge.

Comment: Yes, you'd get the badge, assuming the answer wasn't deleted which would prevent you from awarding the bounty to it. You start the bounty on a question but always award it to an answer to that question.

Comment: Awesome. And I just want to confirm that this is not bad behaviour (since I technically already know who answered the question), correct?

Comment: Try the first bounty step it says one of the possible reasons is to reward an existing answer.

Comment: You shouldn't really just do that action to do that action, but it's not bad behavior in and of itself.....  Do you think the answer is awesome enough to warrant the extra rep? Or do you just do this to trade imaginary internet point for imaginary internet badge?

Comment: I genuinely think that the user's answer was very insightful

Comment: To be fair, there wouldn't be a bad thing either way (I mean it's not like the system can know truly why you gave the bounty). It's just that chasing badges for the sake of chasing badges isn't always useful. In this case, it seems more like 2 birds 1 stone, than anything malicious. So why not?

Comment: That was exactly what I was thinking

Comment: putting a bounty out just to get a badge is the wrong way, the badge should be a nice reward for using the bounty feature.

Comment: Note a much more beneficial (for the community) use of a bounty is to find a good answer that's *worth publicizing*, and let the bounty run for the full 7 days to give it publicity. This way, one hopes, the bounty queue may not be filled with so many off-topic questions, and at least includes some useful content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's not recommended to open a bounty *just* to get a badge, that is technically a valid action on a site that actively encourages participation through gamification.

The purpose of a bounty is typically one of two things:

- To award an existing answer that is more helpful and a greater effort on the answerer's part than the usual +10 or +25 reputation might indicate
- To draw attention to an existing question that doesn't quite have the answer you are looking for. In this case you can specify one of several prescribed descriptions, or fill in your own, of what you are looking for (e.g. just another answer, a canonical source, a modern implementation, etc.).

Notice that in either of these cases, there's no stipulation that the question has to be one you posted or one that someone else posted, nor is there a stipulation that the question can't have an accepted answer.

You can read about how the bounty would be awarded on the [bounty privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) page. This is probably not as useful for you since you've already manually awarded the bounty, but for future readers here are the possible outcomes of a bounty on a question with an accepted answer that is also the highest-scoring answer:

- If you don't choose which answer should get the bounty, half of the bounty will be awarded to the highest scoring answer, and you will have earned the Promoter badge.
- If you do choose which answer should get the bounty, that answer will get the whole bounty, and you will have earned the Promoter badge as well as the Benefactor badge.

I should point out (since your comments hit at some confusion) that bounties can only be awarded to answers; you can't award a bounty to a question (nor can you award a bounty to an answer you posted, regardless of when it was posted). Also, manually awarding bounties at the end of the bounty period or early on in the process doesn't affect the badge(s) earned for *starting* a bounty; those are awarded once you start the bounty and can't be lost even if your bounty is canceled by a moderator (a rare occurrence).